# Image as a variable in JLabel, to be used in if-else

Tags: java, swing, if-statement

I'm a newbie so please be patient

What I want

I have a JPanel on which I have a JButton, a JLabel and a JTextArea. Upon pressing JButton, an image has to be printed inside the JLabel (and some text in JTextArea). This certain image (and text) is determined by if-else statements. Conditions of if-else are based on an integer variable R.

Basically its a survey like question-answer thing I'm trying to make. I use the R to record answers from user. When a user clicks a choice, the value of R gets updated.

Its working fine for the text, but not the image.

For text, I use a String variable yourphone. If the value of R in the end is eg 120, then yourphone gets updated to a string eg. Xperia Z.

I want a similar variable I can use for image, so that the picture of Xperia Z is displayed when the user clicks JButton.

Total value of R is used in if-else statements.

Structure

I initiate variables like this

```
int R=0;
String yourphone;
ImageIcon imageresult;
```

My JPanel which is meant to display result

```
final JPanel result = new JPanel();
    result.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    getContentPane().add(result, "name_17130054294139");
    result.setLayout(null);


    final JTextArea txtrphoneresult = new JTextArea();
    txtrphoneresult.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    txtrphoneresult.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    txtrphoneresult.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    txtrphoneresult.setBounds(448, 515, 469, 121);
    result.add(txtrphoneresult);


    JLabel resultlabel = new JLabel(imageresult);
    resultlabel.setBounds(292, 122, 782, 346);
    result.add(resultlabel);




    JButton btnShowResult = new JButton("Show Result");
    btnShowResult.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    btnShowResult.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(R==1726)
            {
                yourphone = "Samsung Galaxy S4\r\nHTC One\r\nSony Xperia Z";
                ImageIcon imageresult = new ImageIcon("galaxy_one_XperiaZ.jpg");
            }
            else if(R==5002)
            {
                yourphone = "Sony Xperia Z1\r\nSamsung Galaxy Note 3";
                ImageIcon imageresult = new ImageIcon("Note3_sonyZ1.jpg");
            }
            else
            {
                yourphone = "No Results";
            }

            txtrphoneresult.setText(yourphone);

     }
     });
    btnShowResult.setBounds(618, 48, 130, 32);
    result.add(btnShowResult);
```

Problem

The image is not displayed at all.
If there is any other possible way to achieve this, please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you create your `imageresult` inside `if-else` and it's not visible for all method. And you doesn't add your image to `JLabel`.

Make resultlabel as clas member or `final` variable.
Change your code in next way:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        ImageIcon imageresult = null;
        if(R==1726)
        {
            yourphone = "Samsung Galaxy S4\r\nHTC One\r\nSony Xperia Z";
            imageresult = new ImageIcon("galaxy_one_XperiaZ.jpg");
        }
        else if(R==5002)
        {
            yourphone = "Sony Xperia Z1\r\nSamsung Galaxy Note 3";
            imageresult = new ImageIcon("Note3_sonyZ1.jpg");
        }
        else
        {
            yourphone = "No Results";
        }

        resultlabel.setIcon(imageresult)
        txtrphoneresult.setText(yourphone);

 }
```

Comment: Done. Not working. Says imageresult variable cannot be resolved, where I create my JLabel (which I made final like you said). Also multiple markers at this line, at "imageresult = new ImageIcon("Note3_sonyZ1.jpg");"

Comment: Define it in actionPerformed  as recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Declare ImageIcon imageresult before the `if` statement and call

```
resultlabel.setIcon(imageresult)
```

after `txtrphoneresult.setText(yourphone);`

BTW: Don't use null layout/setBounds(). Read about layouts and choose proper one.

Comment: Done. But still not working. Plus after removing "ImageIcon imageresult" from beginning and instead putting "ImageIcon imageresult = null;" inside ActionListener, it shows "imageresult cannot be resolved to a variable" at "final JLabel resultlabel = new JLabel(imageresult);"....Also "Multiple markers at this line" at "ImageIcon imageresult = new ImageIcon("Note3_sonyZ1.jpg");"

Answer (score 1):

where do you set icon for your label.
you mising this line

```
resultlabel.setIcon(imageresult);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `resultLabel` final and change action performed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                ImageIcon imageresult = null;
                if(R == 1726)
                {
                    yourphone = "Samsung Galaxy S4\r\nHTC One\r\nSony Xperia Z";
                    imageresult = new ImageIcon("galaxy_one_XperiaZ.jpg");
                }
                else if(R == 5002)
                {
                    yourphone = "Sony Xperia Z1\r\nSamsung Galaxy Note 3";
                    imageresult = new ImageIcon("Note3_sonyZ1.jpg");
                }
                else
                {
                    yourphone = "No Results";
                }

                txtrphoneresult.setText(yourphone);
                resultlabel.setIcon(imageresult);

            }
```

Comment: Done. Not working. Says imageresult variable cannot be resolved, where I create my JLabel (which I made final like you said). Also multiple markers at this line, at "imageresult = new ImageIcon("Note3_sonyZ1.jpg");"

Comment: don't use imageresult when you create your label, use it only in actionPerformed(), as there is defined.

Answer (score 1):

The image is not displayed because you are not "giving" it to you `JLabel`. You can do it by using the [setIcon()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) method.

You also have a problem with variable declaration. Unlike PHP and some other programming languages, in Java a variable only exists within the brackets (and sub-brackets) `{}` it has been declared in (despite there are some exceptions). For example :

```
public void myMethod() {
    float b = 5f;

    if (true) {
        int a = 6;

        if (true) {
            // a exists, you can do whatever you like with it
            // b exists, you can do whatever you like with it
        }
        // a exists you can do whatever you like with it
        // b exists, you can do whatever you like with it

    } // a is "destroyed"

    // a doesn't exists
    // b still exists
} // b is "destroyed"
// Neither a or b exists
```

You are in the exact same case with the declaration of your variable `imageresult`.

Comment: But if I declare imageresult variable inside ActionListener (like other users suggested), then it says "imageresult variable cannot be result" where I create my JLabel

Comment: Maybe you forgot to import the `ImageIcon` class. Add the line `import javax.swing.ImageIcon;` on top of your java file. Or if you are using Eclipse just do a CTRL+MAJ+O (letter not number).